# Overwrite FILTER in DAX measure

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a measure defined in a cube like

```
Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Amount]), FactSales[External] = TRUE())
```

In PowerBI I would like to override the filter on the `External` column. I've tried

```
All Sales = CALCULATE([Sales], ALL(FactSales[External]))
```

But `ALL(<column>)` only seems to work for context filters.

Is there a way to override the DAX filters as defined on the measure in the cube? using DAX.

Comment: What's wrong with `All Sales = SUM(FactSales[Amount])`?

Comment: @MarcoVos I simplified the example, on the `Sales` measure in the cube there are multiple filters and its only some i wan't to override in the PowerBI. Then i might aswell duplicate the measure in PowerBI minus the 1 filter i want removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you've applied the filter within the [Sales] measure already, so when you define the ALL function, it will only apply to external conext as you've said.

Try this?

```
All Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Amount]), ALL(FactSales[External]))
```

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for. It pretty much means i have to rewrite the cube definition in the powerbi measure. Which i was explicitly trying to avoid. But your probably right its the only possible. Thanks :)